# CasperJS evaluate returns a function

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

How do I get `evaluate` to return the return of the callback?

```
ary = @evaluate ->
  [1, 2, 3]
@echo "LENGTH: #{ary.length}"
@echo "TYPE: #{ary.constructor}"
```

Outputs:

```
LENGTH: undefined
TYPE: function
```

Then it outputs the body of the function, which is some part of Casper.

Based on samples like [this one](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/a9823c523e416cd2d2e4525d2aed45ec35f4755d/samples/metaextract.coffee) I'm expecting `ary` to be my array.  What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

By the way, this works:

```
ary = eval @evaluate ->
  '[1, 2, 3]'
@echo "LENGTH: #{ary.length}"
@echo "TYPE: #{ary.constructor}"
```

Outputs:

```
LENGTH: 3
TYPE: Array
```

Do I have to marshal output from `evaluate` as string (or other primitives)? That's not what the samples show.

**UPDATE #2**

I'm using PhantomJS 1.9.1 which might have something to do with it since I cannot replicate the problem after downgrading to 1.9.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to use the following code on CasperJS 1.1-dev and PhantomJS 1.9.1

```
ary = []
casper.then ->
  ary = @evaluate ->
    [1, 2, 3]

casper.then ->
  @echo "LENGTH: #{ary.length}"
  @echo "TYPE: #{ary.constructor}"
  require('utils').dump(ary)
```

This produces the following output:

```
LENGTH: 3
TYPE: function Array() {
    [native code]
}
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

---

The problem you are facing is most likely due to

```
@echo "LENGTH: #{ary.length}"
@echo "TYPE: #{ary.constructor}"
```

being printed before the `evaluate` has finished executing.

By wrapping both of these in `Casper.then`, you can avoid running into these asynchronous issues.

Comment: My example was perhaps too naive. In reality I having this problem inside callbacks to ```casper.then```, ```casper.thenOpen```, etc.  I am however using CasperJS 1.0.2, which therefore seems the more likely issue. The way I have fixed everything for now is to use PhantomJS 1.9.0.

Comment: Looks like CasperJS < 1.1 isn't supposed to be compatible with PhantomJS >= 1.9. [source](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/releases/tag/1.0.3).